# How to first modified in ruby

Tags: ruby

how i can get the first modified in ruby and the code down below is for the last modified
but i can't get the first modified

```
require 'open-uri'
open("link") do |f|
  f.each_line {|line| p line}
  puts p f.last_modified
end
```

how i can get the first modified in ruby and thanks
so what is the code that i have to write it

and i tried

```
require 'open-uri'
open("link") do |f|
  f.each_line {|line| p line}
  puts p f.first_modified
end
```

and it didn't work

Comment: What's "first_modified"?

Comment: it is n't real code i am just saying how i can get the first modified like last modified but the first

Comment: Yeah, I mean, what are you trying to get? Date of first modification of a resource?

Comment: `Last-Modified` is a HTTP header that indicates the date of the last modification of a resource... There is no "First-Modified" header, because it does not make sense. One could imagine a header named "Created" but what would be the point ? `Last-Modified` exists for the purpose of client-side caching, to see whether a resource needs to be reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

There's no "first_modified" method in OpenURI, because there's no support for it from underlying HTTP protocol. So, what you want to do - it's impossible.

OpenURI docs: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI/Meta.html

Answer (score 0):

First-Modified is not [a standard or common non-standard HTTP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).

Once you request **a header that exists**, you can query it *if it is present* by using the meta hash, even if it is not exposed as a ruby method.

```
require 'open-uri'
p open('http://www.google.com').meta['Your-Header-Name']
```